# Spliting file content into ArrayList

Tags: java

I have a file where I get to read it's content. Now I would like to split each seperate line into an arrayList individually and cant succeed.

This is what I have so far

```
try {
        input = new FileInputStream(test);


        byte testContent[] = new byte[(int) test.length()];
        input.read(testContent);


        String testFile = new String(testContent);
        System.out.println(testFile);

    }
```

An example of file content is as follows,

`0,0,5,13,9,1,0,0,0,0,13,15,10,15,5,0,0,3,15,2,0,11,8,0,0,4,12,0,0,8,8,0,0,5,8,0
0,0,0,12,13,5,0,0,0,0,0,11,16,9,0,0,0,0,3,15,16,6,0,0,0,7,15,16,16,2,0,0,0,0,1,1
0,0,0,4,15,12,0,0,0,0,3,16,15,14,0,0,0,0,8,13,8,16,0,0,0,0,1,6,15,11,0,0,0,1,8,1
0,0,7,15,13,1,0,0,0,8,13,6,15,4,0,0,0,2,1,13,13,0,0,0,0,0,2,15,11,1,0,0,0,0,0,1
0,0,0,1,11,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,8,0,0,0,0,0,1,13,6,2,2,0,0,0,7,15,0,9,8,0,0,5,16,10,0,1`

I would like the above to be in arrays like

`[0,0,5,13,9,1,0,0,0,0,13,15,10,15,5,0,0,3,15,2,0,11,8,0,0,4,12,0,0,8,8,0,0,5,8,0]`
`[0,0,0,12,13,5,0,0,0,0,0,11,16,9,0,0,0,0,3,15,16,6,0,0,0,7,15,16,16,2,0,0,0,0,1,1]`
`[0,0,0,4,15,12,0,0,0,0,3,16,15,14,0,0,0,0,8,13,8,16,0,0,0,0,1,6,15,11,0,0,0,1,8,1]`
`[0,0,7,15,13,1,0,0,0,8,13,6,15,4,0,0,0,2,1,13,13,0,0,0,0,0,2,15,11,1,0,0,0,0,0,1]`
`[0,0,0,1,11,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,8,0,0,0,0,0,1,13,6,2,2,0,0,0,7,15,0,9,8,0,0,5,16,10,0,1]`

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Use a `BufferedReader` to read it line-by-line; split the individual lines using `String.split`.

Comment: You also could use `split()`

Comment: You could arguably use Scanner, but I think the most efficient thing here is to read the whole line then split as @AndyTurner suggested.

Comment: Why did you tag it as `artificial-intelligence`?

Comment: @TDG, who knows what those numbers mean...

Comment: I tagged artificial intelligence just as it is part of a course work involving AI...those numbers are an example for a handwriting recognition to be used with various AI algorithms

Answer (score 1):

How about [`Files.readAllLines()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-):

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(new File(test).toPath());
```

If you're using Java 7, you'll need this version:

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(new File(test).toPath(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [String#split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-)

```
String[] strings= testFile.split("\\r?\\n"); 
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(strings);
```

You can have more details about this method from this question 
[How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

```
String [] lines = testFile.split("\\r?\\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(yourFile));
List<String[]> listOfArrays = new ArrayList<String[]>();

String nextLine;
while((nextLine = br.readLine()) != null){

    String[] lineArray = nextLine.split(",");
    listOfArrays.add(lineArray);

}
```